# Function returning undefined

Tags: javascript

I have a function that calls an API and returns some data:

```
async function getDataAxios(){
        await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/cards/1").then(response => {
                console.log("RESP: ", response.data[0])
                return response
            })
            .catch(err => {
            console.log("Error: ", err)
            return err
        })
}
```

When I log `response.data[0]` inside `getDataAxios()` the expected data is present.
But when I try and return the data to my calling function and log the return data it logs undefined:

`getDataAxios().then(r => console.log(r))`

I have also tried the following:

```
 const resp = getDataAxios().then(resp => console.log("Data 2: ", resp)).catch(
    err => {
        console.log("An error has occurred: ", err)
        return err;
    }
  )
    console.log(resp)
```

Full code:

```
function App() {
    getDataAxios().then(r => console.log(r))
}

async function getDataAxios(){
        await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/cards/1").then(response => {
                console.log("RESP: ", response.data[0])
                return response
            })
            .catch(err => {
            console.log("Error: ", err)
            return err
        })
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Your `getDataAxios` does not return anything.  No need for it to be async, just do `return axios.get(...)..`

Comment: That does work, but i'm not really sure why. How is doing `return axios.get("http://localhost:8080/cards/1")` different from `axios.get("http://localhost:8080/cards/1").then(resp => { console.log("RESP: ", resp.data[0]) return resp })`

Comment: The latter `return`s the value from the `then` callback, not from `getDataAxios`. The former will return the entire promise from `getDataAxios`, allowing it to be used outside.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding here some more details, since the comment was not very detailed.

You have

```
async function getDataAxios(){
  await axios.get(...).then(...).catch(...);
}
```

and

```
function App() {
  getDataAxios().then(r => console.log(r))
}
```

---

The `getDataAxios` method does not return anything. The `then` inside it does return a value, but that is not returned from the actual `getDataAxios` function.

Nothing wrong with that on its own, if the `then` code is all you wanted to perform.

But you then call it in the `App` and use `then` on it, `getDataAxios().then(r => console.log(r))`. The `r` here will contain whatever was returned from the `getDataAxios` which is nothing, so the `r` will be `undefined.`

Adding the `return` to the `getDataAxios` will return the promise. And since the return value type of `axios` is a promise you do not have to specify `async`, nor `await` for it.

So you can use

```
function getDataAxios(){
  return axios.get(...).then(...).catch(...);
}
```

and now you can use it as you already do, as

```
function App() {
  getDataAxios().then(r => console.log(r))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am then unable to use the data returned from the `getDataAxios()` outside of the `then()`. If I try and get the assign the return value to a variable it returns a promise: `const z = getDataAxios().then(r => console.log(r))
    
console.log(z)`

Comment: @HLT for that you will have to return the `r` and the outside code will have to `await` the `getDataAxios`. So somthing like `const z = await getDataAxios().then(r => {
  console.log(r); return r;
});
console.log(z);`

Answer (score 0):

Turn the response into a constant and than store data in it and than return it. Do this instead.

```
async function getDataAxios(){
    await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/cards/1").then(response => {
            console.log("RESP: ", response.data[0])
            const response = response.data[0]
            return response
        })
        .catch(err => {
        console.log("Error: ", err)
        return err
    })
  }
```

Or you can do this

```
       async function getDataAxios(){
     await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/cards/1").then(response => {
            console.log("RESP: ", response.data[0])
            return response.data[0]
        })
        .catch(err => {
        console.log("Error: ", err)
        return err
    })
   }
```

Comment: Both of these functions return undefined.